# PHP Form to update records in MS SQLSRV

Tags: php, html, forms, sqlsrv

I've spent all day researching how to get this to work with no luck.

I have a HTML form that's dynamically created using php depending on how many entries there are in my MS SQL table. The form is pre-populated with data from the table that I want the user to be able to update themselves.

```
<div class="selection">
            <h2>Update Courses</h2>
    <?php

    $handle_password = fopen("../../../Password","r") or die("Unable to read Datalake password!");
    $connectionOptions = array(
        "database" => "",
        "uid" => "",
        "pwd" => ""
    );
    $connectionOptions["pwd"] = fread($handle_password,filesize("../../../Password"));
    fclose($handle_password);

    $conn = sqlsrv_connect('hostname', $connectionOptions);
    if ( $conn === false) {
        die ('Cannot connect to Datalake');
    }

$query = "SELECT [course], [hours] FROM academycourses";
        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
        $num_rows = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
        
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
            <form action="courseupdate.php" method="POST">
                <div class="segment">
                    <div class="narrative">
                        <label for="course">Course:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="course" value="<?php echo $row['course']?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="settings">
                        <label class="tickslabel" for="hours">Hours</label>
                        <input class="ticks" type="number" name="hours" value="<?php echo $row['hours']?>">
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
                <button type="submit" value="<?php echo $row['course']?>" name="update">Update</button>
                <?php } ?>
            </form>
```

When the `update` button is pressed, it then goes into the php script that handles the update-

```
<?php 
        if(isset($_POST['update'])){
        $id = $_POST['update'];
        $course=$_POST['course']; 
        $hours=$_POST['hours']; 
        $handle_password = fopen("../../../Password","r") or die("Unable to read password!");
        $connectionOptions = array(
            "database" => "",
            "uid" => "",
            "pwd" => ""
        );
        $connectionOptions["pwd"] = fread($handle_password,filesize("../../../Password"));
        fclose($handle_password);

        $conn = sqlsrv_connect('hostname', $connectionOptions);
        if ( $conn === false) {
            die ('Cannot connect to Datalake');
        }

        if ( sqlsrv_begin_transaction( $conn ) === false ) {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));
        }
        $course = $_POST['update'];
        $sqlquery = "UPDATE academycourses SET [course] = ? ,[hours] = ? WHERE [course] = ?";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sqlquery, array($_POST['update'], $_POST['hours']));
        //$delete->bind_param('row', $id);
        sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
        
    
        sqlsrv_close ($conn );

        header("Location: editcourses.php");
        
    }
    ?>
```

I currently have 3 rows of data in my table

| course | hours |
| --- | --- |
| course1 | 2 |
| course2 | 4 |
| course3 | 6 |

If I change the value of course2 to course4 and its hours value to 8, when I press the `update` button, it loads into the update php page but the $_POST superglobals passed are always for the last row in the db, `coure: "course3"` and `hours: "6"` but `update: "course2"` will be correct.

Am I missing something obvious or going about this the wrong way?

Thank you for reading

Comment: You may consider the following: 1) You have three parameter holders (`?`) in the `UPDATE` statement, but only two actual values. 2) You may use `sqlsrv_query()` for one-time queries, because the function does both statement preparation and statement execution. A simple example: `$course1 = $_POST['update']; $course2 = $_POST['update']; $hours = $_POST['hours']; $sqlquery = "UPDATE academycourses SET [course] = ? ,[hours] = ? WHERE [course] = ?"; $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlquery, array($course1, $hours, $course2])); if ($stmt === false) {echo "Error"; die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));}`